# Combining multiple strpos() in an if () statement

Tags: php, if-statement, strpos

I'm trying to make added user agent stay on a page. If user agent is not detected, then redirect.

This code works

```php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (strpos($useragent, "useragent") === false) {
  header("Location: http://google.com/");
}
```

So I tried to add multiple user agent like this but didn't work.

```php
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (
    strpos($useragent, "agent1") === false ||
    strpos($useragent, "agent2") === false ||
    strpos($useragent, "agent2") === false
) {
      header("Location: http://google.com/");
}
```

Comment: You must use `&&` instead of `||`. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead.

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$agents = ['agent1', 'agent2', 'agent3']; //array of predefined names of agents

if (!preg_match('/' . implode('|', $agents) . '/i', $useragent)) { //check if current user agent is not enlisted
    header("Location: http://google.com/");
}
```

Comment: Works, but I want it needed it Iike: stay on page if user agent is listed. Go away if your user agent isn't listed. Got Eric code.

Comment: It works like this. It redirects when user agent is not found in predefined list.

Comment: Nice to hear that. If you don't mind, please accept answers which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want a code that is simpler to update than your successive `strpos()`. Also, you should search case-insensitively. And firing the PCRE engine at each page access may not be optimal.

So I would keep the `stripos()` approach like this:

```
<?php
$partial_allowed_UA_names = ['mozilla', 'chrome', 'safari']; # <----- Config here.
$go_away = true;
foreach ($partial_allowed_UA_names as $v) {
    if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $v) !== false) {
        $go_away = false;
        break;
    }
}
if ($go_away) header('Location: https://www.google.com/');
?>
```

Best regards